# Twython: How to update profile banner?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, twython

What am I doing wrong?

```
twitter = twython.Twython(api_key, api_secret, access_token, token_secret) 
banner_file = open('banner.jpg', 'rb')
twitter.update_profile_banner_image(banner=banner_file)
```

Calling this returns:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 202, in
>   _request
>       content = response.json()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 812,
>   in json
>       return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/**init**.py", line 319, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tuit.py", line 45, in
>   
>       twitter.update_profile_banner_image(banner=banner)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twython/endpoints.py", line
>   493, in update_profile_banner_image
>       return self.post('account/update_profile_banner', params=params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line
>   270, in post
>       return self.request(endpoint, 'POST', params=params, version=version)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 260, in
>   request
>       api_call=url)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 205, in
>   _request
>       Unable to decode.') twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Response was not valid JSON.                                Unable to decode.